# What distribution is this density?

Tags: normal-distribution

Is the density $p(\mathbf{x}) \propto \exp\left(-||\mathbf{x}||_2\right)$ from a known/named distribution family?

It's obviously not Gaussian, that's $p(\mathbf{x})\propto \exp\left(-||\mathbf{x}||_2^2\right)$.

Comment: Maybe Laplace ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution

Comment: If $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}$ then it's Laplace, but what if $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n>1$. I.e. $p(\mathbf{x}) \propto \exp\left(\sqrt{\mathbf{x}_1^2+\mathbf{x}_2^2+\cdot+\mathbf{x}_n^2}\right)$? At least on wikipedia, this does not look like a multivariate Laplace density. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_Laplace_distribution#Probability_density_function